# Numpy to assess letters as integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In 3d arrays, I know I can transform integers with the following:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], np.int32)
x[x==0] = 99
print (x[0:])
    [[99  1  1  2]
     [99  5 99 99]
     [ 2 99  3  3]]
```

---

Is there a way to input strings into matrices? For example something like this?

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0, 3, 3]], np.int32)
x[x==0] = int('x') ## This might be something like str('x), but I want it to 
                   ## equal 0
print (x[0:])
    [[x  1  1  2]
     [x  5  x  x]
     [2  x  3  3]]
```

Comment: `ord` can be used but need to remember all the replaced places since the value will be in `int` format to be used to filter in later use.

Comment: Are you looking for a function that calls int(x) on any string but defaults to 0 instead of raising an exception if the string is `’’` or `’xyz’` or the like? You can write that as a trivial wrapper using try/except. And then you can broadcast that function over an array of strings to get an array of ints.

Comment: hi @MaNKuR can you explain that more? I'm brand new to python so still learning. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Or if you’re actually trying to store strings like `’x’` into your array—you _can_ do that, but numpy arrays have data types: an array of ints can’t store anything but ints. You can create an array with data type `object` which can store any Python values, but then you lose most of the speed and space benefits of numpy. (It can still be useful just for the convenience benefits of being able to write array-wide operations.)

Comment: I don’t think you want `ord` here. That function turns each character into an int with the corresponding code point. For example, `’a’` is code point #97, so `ord(‘a’)` is the number 97.

Comment: hi @abarnert , thank you for your response! Well, to be honest I am learning python right now and there is a problem that wants me to run mathematical equations on everything except for zero. So I probably could just use a rule to exclude zero and it would be wayy easier than switching it to x. Honestly I am new enough to the language that it is hard to ask concise and clear questions haha.

Comment: Your example with `99` is obviously wrong. Please update that, to make sense.

Comment: thanks @JohanL , fixed it

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`nan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html)? To replace all 0s with nans so you don't accidentally get something that looks like a meaningful result when it isn't, you can do `a[a==0] = np.nan`. But in that case, it might be even better to just run your operation on `a[a==0]` instead of on `a`. (It depends on whether the positions of the values have a meaning that has to be preserved.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for *can* be done, but only by changing from an array of numbers to an array of `object`—that is, general-anything-at-all values:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], dtype=object)
>>> x[x==0] = 'x'
>>> x
array([['x', 1, 1, 2],
       ['x', 5, 'x', 'x'],
       [2, 'x', 3, 3]], dtype=object)
```

But this is probably not what you want. Most of the speed and space savings of numpy come from the fact that arrays have a specific data type; if you use the generic `object`, they're no smaller, and not much faster, than just using a list of lists. If you're only using `numpy` for syntactic convenience rather than space or speed benefits, that may be fine, but it's definitely something to think about before you do it.

Also, an array of objects follows the usual Python rules for any arithmetic on those objects. For example:

```
>>> x+2
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

That doesn't seem very useful.

---

If you're looking for a special "marker value" that prevents you from accidentally thinking some value is meaningful when it actually wasn't, you can do that with floats, although not with ints, by using [`nan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], dtype=np.float64)
>>> x[x==0] = np.nan
>>> x
array([[nan,  1.,  1.,  2.],
       [nan,  5., nan, nan],
       [ 2., nan,  3.,  3.]])
```

A `nan` can be stored in a `float64` slot, so you still have all the space and speed benefits of a fixed-type array. And (by default), operations on `nan` don't raise an exception, they just return `nan`. So:

```
>>> x+2
array([[nan,  3.,  3.,  4.],
       [nan,  7., nan, nan],
       [ 4., nan,  5.,  5.]])
```

---

In some cases, it may be even better to just leave the array alone and operate on the array with a mask:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], dtype=np.int64)
>>> x[x!=0] += 2
>>> x
array([[0, 3, 3, 4],
       [0, 7, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 5]])
```

Or, if your indices don't matter, only your values, you can even do this (the simplest version, ignoring even axes):

```
>>> x = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2, 0,3,3]], dtype=np.int64)
>>> y = x[x!=0]
>>> y+2
array([3, 3, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5])
```

Comment: you're awesome, thank you so much for your thoughtful response @abarnert